# Print two equal size arrays aligned by rows

Tags: python, arrays, arr

How can I print  two equal size arrays aligned by rows?

For example:

```
a = np.array([[1],
              [2],
              [3],
              [4]])

rv = np.array([["R1x ="],
               ["R1y ="],
               ["R5x ="],
               ["R5y ="]])

print(rv, a)
```

I want that the code prints the code below:

```
R1x = 1
R1y = 2
R5x = 3
R5y = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip` for that:

```
for val, string in zip(a.flatten(), rv.flatten()):
    print(f"{string} {val}")

# out:
R1x = 1
R1y = 2
R5x = 3
R5y = 4
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked on this code! However in a more complex code that I have the output was "R1x = 1 2 3 4".

Comment: THen the structure of the array is likely different. In the end, you always need to pass 2 1D lists/iterables to zip.